# html content in A4 size overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to stop the overflowing of text and have the A4 paper start again from the next page when the page is over. Something on the lines of the screenshot attached:

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a4size">
    <p>Text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px #555;
  padding: 45px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.a4size{
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
}
```

Here's my **[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cfztpqk4/)**

I have gone through some solutions mentioned here but to no avail.

Comment: Hey @Elaine Byene did you found any solution fo this?

Answer (score 0):

Add style `overflow:hidden` to A4 size div

```
.a4size{
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This hides the remaining text. I want the remaining text to start from another A4 size div as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Then you can avoid it by reducing padding, making font smaller and reducing line-height

Comment: Try font-size: 13px;

Comment: That's NOT the solution. The text runs into several pages.

Comment: Text automatically runs into several pages when content size is increasing. Please ask your question clearly

Comment: Let me explain again: I have text content with over 50,000 words. The jsfiddle demo shows barely just about 1,500 words because I can't put up 50,000 words in the demo. I have to separate it page by page in A4 size but the text is overflowing after the 1st page as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Is this for print or for viewing on screen?

Comment: Good question, Someone will answer

Comment: @elaine-byene 
did you find its solution?